# No audio Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, sound

[image]

I had Kubuntu installed on my laptop. The audio was not working. Also, I could not connect it to an external screen via HDMI and I couldn't find any help for solving these problems.
Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 22.04. The audio is still not working. If I go to the Audio settings I can see the level of the audio in a Youtube video (like you see in the picture), but I don't hear anything. If I test the speakers I don't hear anything.
I followed various posts, updated and reinstalled drivers, mainly copying command lines in the Terminal,  but nothing seems to work.
Can anybody help me?

HERE IS THE OUTPUT OF THE COMMAND journalctl -k | grep -Ei "ALSA|HDA|sof[-]|HDMI|snd[_-]|sound|hda.codec|hda.intel":

```
nov 08 10:14:47 teo-TravelMate-B117-M kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
nov 08 10:14:49 teo-TravelMate-B117-M kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC255: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
nov 08 10:14:49 teo-TravelMate-B117-M kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
nov 08 10:14:49 teo-TravelMate-B117-M kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
nov 08 10:14:49 teo-TravelMate-B117-M kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
nov 08 10:14:49 teo-TravelMate-B117-M kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
nov 08 10:14:49 teo-TravelMate-B117-M kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x12
nov 08 10:14:49 teo-TravelMate-B117-M kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input12
nov 08 10:14:49 teo-TravelMate-B117-M kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13
```

Results of `lspci -knn | grep Audio -A3` :

```
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller [8086:2284] (rev 35) 
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller [1025:108c] 
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel 
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel 00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #1 [8086:22c8] (rev 35)
```

Comment: Append the output of `lspci -knn | grep Audio -A3`

Comment: 00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller [8086:2284] (rev 35)
 Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller [1025:108c]
 Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
 Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #1 [8086:22c8] (rev 35)

Comment: What should I do now?

Comment: Can you help me, @RA https://askubuntu.com/users/1592865/r-a ?

Comment: Attach output of this command: `journalctl -k | grep -Ei "ALSA|HDA|sof[-]|HDMI|snd[_-]|sound|hda.codec|hda.intel"`

Comment: Please edit your post and put outputs there

Comment: nov 06 18:21:45 teo-TravelMate-B117-M kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
nov 06 18:21:45 teo-TravelMate-B117-M kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC255: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
nov 06 18:21:45 teo-TravelMate-B117-M kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
nov 06 18:21:45 teo-TravelMate-B117-M kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)

Comment: nov 06 18:21:45 teo-TravelMate-B117-M kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
nov 06 18:21:45 teo-TravelMate-B117-M kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
nov 06 18:21:45 teo-TravelMate-B117-M kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x12
nov 06 18:21:45 teo-TravelMate-B117-M kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input12
nov 06 18:21:45 teo-TravelMate-B117-M kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13

Comment: I had to divide it in two parts

Comment: Please edit your post and attach there

Comment: I hav done it and attached it