# Still no Audio ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, 22.04

I had kubuntu un my Acer TravelMate B117-M laptop. The audio stopped working and I couldn't fix it. After some months I switched to ubuntu 22.04. Still no audio.

I asked the same question and it didn't work: [No audio Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1482036/no-audio-ubuntu-22-04?noredirect=1#comment2613243_1482036)

I tried following many threads, like this one [Only dummy audio on laptop when updating from Ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436452/only-dummy-audio-on-laptop-when-updating-from-ubuntu-22-04-to-22-10) or this one [No Audio Ubuntu 22.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1462316/no-audio-ubuntu-22-10)

I reinstalled pulseaudio. Still no audio.

If I use an external speaker or headphones I can hear everything.
Any suggestion?